# Simple operation with lagged values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rolling-computation

I need to calculate line-wise simple operations using lagged values, for example the sum for a variable for the previous x years

I tried:

```
toy %>% 
  group_by(student) %>% 
  mutate(lag_passed = sum(lag(passed, n = 5, order_by = year, default = 0)))

toy %>% 
  group_by(student) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(lag_passed = lapply(passed, function(x) sum(lag(x, n = 5, default = 0))))
```

Reproducible examples. Task sum the number of passed tests in the previous five years.

```
toy <- data.frame(student = rep("A",10),
year=c(1:10), 
passed=c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1))

   student year passed
1        A    1      0
2        A    2      0
3        A    3      0
4        A    4      1
5        A    5      2
6        A    6      0
7        A    7      0
8        A    8      0
9        A    9      0
10       A   10      1

expected <- data.frame(student = rep("A",10),
year=c(1:10), 
passed=c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,0,1), 
lag_passed=c(0,0,0,0,1,3,3,3,4,3))

   student year passed lag_passed
1        A    1      0          0
2        A    2      0          0
3        A    3      0          0
4        A    4      1          0
5        A    5      2          1
6        A    6      0          3
7        A    7      0          3
8        A    8      1          3
9        A    9      0          4
10       A   10      1          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runner::sum_run()` will help here.  using `idx = year` is optional, unless you have missing values in some of the years, in which case it will take into account those missing years too, which is however, not the case with sample data.  grouping on `student` is added because, in actual you may want to carry out the operation for each student.

```r
toy <- data.frame(student = rep("A",10),
                  year=c(1:10), 
                  passed=c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,0,1))
library(dplyr)

library(runner)
toy %>% group_by(student) %>%
  mutate(lag_passed = sum_run(x = passed,
                             idx = year,
                             k = 5,
                             lag = 1))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Groups:   student [1]
#>    student  year passed lag_passed
#>    <chr>   <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 A           1      0         NA
#>  2 A           2      0          0
#>  3 A           3      0          0
#>  4 A           4      1          0
#>  5 A           5      2          1
#>  6 A           6      0          3
#>  7 A           7      0          3
#>  8 A           8      1          3
#>  9 A           9      0          4
#> 10 A          10      1          3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another rolling sum solution with `zoo::rollapply`:

```
f <- function(x) {zoo::rollapply(x, 6, sum, align = 'right', partial = TRUE) - x}

expected %>% 
    group_by(student) %>% 
    arrange(year) %>% 
    mutate(lag_passed2 = f(passed)) %>%
    ungroup()

#    student  year passed lag_passed lag_passed2
#    <chr>   <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 A           1      0          0           0
#  2 A           2      0          0           0
#  3 A           3      0          0           0
#  4 A           4      1          0           0
#  5 A           5      2          1           1
#  6 A           6      0          3           3
#  7 A           7      0          3           3
#  8 A           8      1          3           3
#  9 A           9      0          4           4
# 10 A          10      1          3           3
```

lag_passed2 created with the helper function is the same as `lag_passed`. The idea is to calculate a sliding window sum with a window length of 6 (allow partial window at begining by `partial = T` and `align = 'right'`), then substract the `passed` value of the current years.

---

Note: the helper function `f` can be replaced to a simpler one by specifying the window using offsets and default right alignment as pointed out by @G. Grothendieck:

```
f <- function(x) rollapplyr(x, list(-seq(5)), sum, partial = TRUE, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Note that `rollapply` also accepts offsets and `rollapplyr`, with r on the end, defaults to `align = "right"` so this would also work `rollapplyr(x, list(-seq(5)), sum, partial = TRUE, fill = 0)`

Comment: Thanks for the info :) I didn't notice that. `rollapply` and `rollapplyr` are more flexible than I thought.